# How to branch based on the documentclass?

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, branching

I have a `macros.tex` file where I keep my macros and 
I use them with different document classes. 
I want to skip including some of my macros 
based on the document class (e.g. if it is `beamer`).
How can I branch based the document class?

Comment: \@ifclassloaded{class}[true}{false}  See CTAN source2e https://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e

Comment: There's `\@ifclassloaded{<class>}{<true>}{<false>}`. And other, related, commands....